# Is there a good library c/c++/java to generate video with special effects , transitions from a set of images?

Tags: c++, video, slideshow, mp4

I need to develop a video generator that takes in a set of images, music files and outputs mp4 videos. The platform is linux. Was wondering if there are any existing libraries that can do this job ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Processing](http://processing.org/) can do what you want.

Comment: Just checked it, its too low level i think, all i need is few image filters and tweening ability.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageMagick for video part. It has both good graphics/video library and corresponding console application. For sound embedding use gstreamer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as far as I know, imagemagick can animate a set of images but it cannot produce a sequence of image e.g. tweening